# rm -iR does not work inside a loop

Tags: shell-script, rm, interactive

Here is my loop

```
ls -ltrd * | head -n -3 | awk '{print $NF}' | while read y; do

rm -iR $y

done
```

output:

> rm: descend into directory `oct_temp17`? rm: descend into directory
>   `oct_temp18`? rm: descend into directory `oct_temp19`? ....

It does not prompt for user confirmation which rm -i should ideally when run manually.

I m using bash shell on Linux 3.10

I am naive to Unix / Linux. Can you please suggest how can i make the script ask me for confirmation for every folder from the ls output ?

Comment: might have less to do it being a loop, but the fact you are using STDIN for piping in data instead of user interaciton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Why you example did not work as expected

`rm`'s prompts need STDIN to receive your feedback. In your example you used STDIN to pipe a list to the `while` loop though, thus `rm` was getting the answers to it's prompts from your `ls`/`head`/`awk` commands, instead of the user.

The solution is to not use STDIN for providing the list to the loop - e.g.:

```
for y in $(ls -ltrd * | head -n -3 | awk '{print $NF}'); do
  rm -iR $y
done
```

### 2. Safer way to do this

Be ready for filenames containing spaces (you don't need `awk`, to get the filename, you can just tell `ls` to only print the filename in the 1st place):

```
IFS=
for y in $(ls -1qtrd * | head -n -3); do
  rm -iR "$y"
done
```

### 3. An easier way to do this

As Archemar pointed out: You don't even need a loop (as long as there are no spaces in filenames).

```
rm -iR $(ls -1qtrd * | head -n -3)
```

Comment: 1) or else `rm -iR $(ls -ltrd * | head -n -3 | awk '{print $NF}')`
2) and mandatory thou shall not parse ls : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls